# sql server procedure exec sub procedures deadlock continues processing

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, deadlock

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a stored procedure X, which execs 2 other stored procedures:

```
create procedure X
begin
   exec A
   exec B
end
```

Stored procedure A has a transaction in it

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
begin transaction
  insert into .....
  set @ReadingID = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
commit transaction
```

If stored procedure A fails with a deadlock, does stored procedure B get executed after the user has acknowledged the deadlock message, or is stored procedure X aborted?

I had expected X to be aborted, but my live data indicates that B may have been run after A has failed - or at least that's one explanation of the data - or at least the users description of what appeared to happen.

Comment: You can use TRY...CATCH statement, to make sure, it there is an exception in sp-a, you can stop executing the sp-b. If there is no exceptional handling within sp-X and SP-A, the definitely it will execute the SP-B